# How to do text strike out in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something like 'to do list'. I want to strike out text on the task but it didn't work so i tried wtih background color or something.
`

```
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('task').length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('task')[i].onclick = function(){
        this.parentElement.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    }
}`
```

Before that I'm creating new element which have 'task' class. 
Someone know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? Does this code not work ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. can i send full code here via pastebin?

Comment: To past your code, you can use [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

So it must be [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and you need to amend element's [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Also I would recommend to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), as it's the most reliable way to bind events to elements.

```js
var tasks = document.getElementsByClassName('task');
for (var i = 0, len = tasks.length; i < len; i++) {
  tasks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.task { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="task">Task 1</span></li>
  <li><span class="task">Task 2</span></li>
  <li><span class="task">Task 3</span></li>
  <li><span class="task">Task 4</span></li>
  <li><span class="task">Task 5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @szpanel If you click on *Run code snippet* above and test it, you will see that it works.

Comment: Yes i know. I see it but on my webpage it doesnt work. Can you check my code? https://pastebin.com/WhpvjdV0

Comment: Maybe it's because i have background-color in css?

Comment: If you already use jQuery, you should use some jQuery functions.

Comment: Im new in javascript and jquery so at this moment i want to understand it just in js

Comment: @szpanel It doesn't work because you first bind `click` event to all `.task` elements and then you add these elements dynamically. You should either bind event to the element right after its was inserted in the DOM or use [delegated event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/1249581).

Comment: It will be difficult, as you could see my english is bad and im new in this so.. XD but thank you so much i will read it and try do something

Answer (score 0):

How about `this.style`?

```
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('task').length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('task')[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJGXNr

Comment: I send it in comment below